# Hiding multiple objects using MS Access VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-access

Can someone please help me with the VBA code. I am very new to MS Access. How to make multiple fileds invisible/hide using VBA code?

I am working on creating MS Acceess form. I have a requirement, 3 fields needs to be hidden if a condition is selected from a filed. If example: I have a column gender with values (Male, female and other). If I select other from the gender field three other fields lets say (X, Y and Y) need to go invisible. I am unable to hide all three fileds at a time. Below is the code I am using. Can someone please help me with this.

```
Private Sub gender_Click()
If gender.Value = "other" Then
Me.X.Visible = True And Me.Y.Visible = True And Me.X.Visible = True
Else
Me.X.Visible = False And Me.Y.Visible = False And Me.X.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
Me.X.Visible = True And Me.Y.Visible = True And Me.X.Visible = True
```

does not do what I think you think it does. Everything to right of the equals sign is evaluated before it is applied to the Visible parameter. This means that if  all these are true, the result is true:

```
True
    And
Me.Y.Visible = True 
    And 
Me.X.Visible = True
```

Instead you can do like this:

```
Me.X.Visible = True
Me.Y.Visible = True
Me.X.Visible = True
```

or even

```
Me.X.Visible = (gender.Value = "other")
Me.Y.Visible = (gender.Value = "other")
Me.X.Visible = (gender.Value = "other")
```

in which case you won't need an `If` at all

Comment: Thank you so much Sam, the code without If works perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`And` is logical operator. You don't need to use it here

```vb
Private Sub gender_Click()
    If gender.Value = "other" Then
        Me.X.Visible = True 
        Me.Y.Visible = True
        Me.X.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.X.Visible = False 
        Me.Y.Visible = False 
        Me.X.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Or If you want one to set property at single line

```vb
Private Sub gender_Click()
    If gender.Value = "other" Then
        Me.X.Visible = True : Me.Y.Visible = True : Me.X.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.X.Visible = False : Me.Y.Visible = False : Me.X.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```